# Проблема с обновлением php на Denwer (пустая страница)

Tags: php, windows, denwer

Решил обновить php на пакете Denwer (Версия: Денвер-3 2013-06-02) до версии php5.6. Скачал 32 битную safe версию. Залил все файлы в каталог \usr\local\php5 , предварительно очистив его. Затем переименовал php.ini-development в php.ini. Теперь проблема в том, что вместо html кода сервер выдает **пустые** страницы без всяких предупреждений. Не подскажите в чем может быть причина?

ps
Видел видеоурок в котором все получилось. Не пишите пожалуйста, что я должен устанавливать другой сервер. интересует именно Denwer.

Comment: Попробуйте просто запустить php.exe -v в командной строке. Если проблема с библиотеками, то выскочит ошибка

Comment: а апач в логи пишет что-то? думаю первым делом надо туда глянуть.........Вообще `php 5.6` не работает вроде как с `apache2.2` а только с `2.4`. Поэтому странно что вообще что-то завелось. Поэтому как минимум думаю стоит апач проапгрейдить. А также посмотреть настройки с предыдущей версии php и перекинуть их на новую. А также возможно в коде есть какие-то вещи, которые на php старой версии позволялись, а в 5.6 выкинулись и теперь из-за этого не работает.......... а вообще я даже не уверен что денвер позволяет что-то самолично улучшать у себя ибо там всё вшито хрен пойми что где

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov пробовал, там нет проблем, выдает что установлена версия 5.6 и все ОК

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в логах чисто , в консоли запуска сервера тоже чисто

Comment: Посмотрите в php.ini похоже вы используете <? а по умолчанию в ini short_open_tag = Off, надо поставить в on

Comment: @АлексейШиманский использую полные теги , вот здесь парень php5.6 на денвер вешает https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bI7gRsV6cdw

Comment: Файл, содержащий только <?php phpinfo(); ?> тоже пустой открывается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да

Comment: А в апаче настраивается как модуль или как fast cgi? Если как модуль, то видимо, вместе с php надо обновить mod_php в апаче

Comment: @perfect вам не надо только мне отвечать ;-)

Comment: а участник pavel mayorov другого мнения ))

Comment: выкинуть денвер и поставить OpenServer там php вплоть до 7.1 денвер вроде уже не поддерживается

Answer (score 1):

Для php 5.6 необходим apache версии не меньше 2.4 (сейчас в папке php5 денвера, скорее всего, отсутствует файл php5apache2_2.dll, который является модулем апача и прописывается в httpd.conf).

Неплохой гайд по миграции на denwer на apache 2.4 здесь: http://shra.ru/2016/03/migraciya-konfiguracii-denwer-dlya-apache-2-2-na-apache-2-4/#axzz4KgaAAzr4

Ещё нужно обязательно проверить, чтобы php был скомпилирован в той же версии VC что и апач. (для 5.6 это VC14)

На будущее, можно посмотреть логи сервера (Z:\usr\local\apache\logs\error.log) или попытаться запустить httpd.exe через консоль - критические ошибки (при невозможности запуска сервера) выводятся только туда.

К сожалению, мне не удалось где-либо найти полный гайд по конфигурации apache 2.4 + php 5.6 для denwer, поэтому над конфигами придётся чуточку самому посидеть.